# Django ModelForm not saving any data

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Using django 3, I have a model and a modelform:

```
class Upload(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)

class UploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Upload
        fields = ['content',]

    def clean_content(self):
        content = self.cleaned_data.get('content')
        if len(content) > MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH:
            raise forms.ValidationError('This content is too long')
```

The view looks like this:

```
def upload_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = UploadForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance = instance.save()
        form = UploadForm()
```

I am prompting the user to upload the contents only. After saving the form, even if I input some text inside the form, in the database it gets a value of NULL. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

correct it as follows

```
if request.method == "POST":
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        # instance.something = something
        instance.save()
        return redirect('/')
else:
     form = UploadForm()
return render(request, 'your.html', {'form': form})
```